# Macro can not find a word in a locked sheet in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that if I can not find a word, it displays a message, and closes the form

The code works fine, but if I put a password on the sheet, it says all the time that it does not find the word

If I remove the password, then yes the word finds

The code of the search

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheets("sheet1").Range("D:D").Find(What:="word", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
If r Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "The word was not found"
End 'Closing the form
End If
```

The password code

```
Dim wks1 As Worksheet
For Each wks1 In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    wks1.Protect "1234", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
    Next wks1
```

I would be happy for any help solve my problem

If my question is not understood please write to me

Comment: When you open the workbook there is an input box where you have to put password?

Comment: If i understood your question try this One: first line code SheetName.Unprotect Password:=yourPassword
And this at the end:

SheetName.Protect Password:=yourPassword

Answer (score 0):

this is an example that works.

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pwd As String
Dim r As Range

pwd = "pippo"

For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Unprotect Password:=pwd
Next ws

Set r = Sheets("Foglio1").Range("D:D").Find(What:="word", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

If r Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "parola non trovata"
Else
    MsgBox "parola trovata!"
End If

For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Protect Password:=pwd
Next ws

End Sub
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Protect the sheet in VBA with the parameter `UserInterFaceOnly`, then the VBA can find the word in a protected sheet that does not even allow selection of protected cells.

For example, in the ThisWorkbook module use

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Protect Password:="secret", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, userinterfaceonly:=True
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Then you can run the code without first unprotecting the sheet.

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Range

Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:D").Find(What:="word", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

If r Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "not found"
Else
    MsgBox "found"
End If
End Sub
```

[image]